# Bounds on the construction of regular expressions' intersection operator

Tags: time-complexity, regular-language, space-complexity, complexity-theory

There are references on the exponential worst-case of the intersection operator for regular expressions (see [1]). However, I was wondering if there are similar results for the construction process itself?

Concretely, given two regular expressions $E_1$ and $E_2$ whose intersection can be represented by a regular expression of polynomial size, is the construction process itself bounded by exponential time or memory in the worst-case?

[1] [Succinctness of the Complement and Intersection of Regular Expressions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2869)

Comment: Are you aware of the problem of [minimizing a regex](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31630/how-can-one-actually-minimize-a-regular-expression)?

Comment: Or  [regex equality](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12278/123159)?

Comment: @plshelp thanks for the links! Could you elaborate a bit more on how do they imply an answer to my question? I don't quite see the reduction.