# Non-isomorphic minimal non-deterministic finite automata

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

Can somebody provide an example of two equivalent (recognizing the same language) minimal non-deterministic automata (NFA) which are not isomorphic?

Comment: See the comment by mikero on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/computing-the-minimal-nfa-for-a-dfa

Answer (score 11):

See the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220530733_A_note_about_minimal_non-deterministic_automata) (postscript)

Arnold, Dicky, Nivat. A note about minimal non-deterministic automata

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing!  Their paper includes a nice example.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Along a different line: the set $L_6$ of strings of the form $a^n$, where $n$ is *not* a multiple of 6 has two very different minimal NFAs.
[image: Two minimal NFAs for $L_6$.]

One of them is basically the minimal DFA, the other guesses whether it is not a multiple of 2 or not a multiple of 3.

Comment: But isn't the later automaton not minimal? One can discard the state a and set b and d as inital states (and moving the accepted states to c, e and f). So a minimal NFA has actually 5 states

Comment: That depends on the actual definition of NFA. You are right: I silently assumed that NFAs have one initial state. That's at least a frequent definition, see, e.g., the Wikipedia article on NFAs.